# guidelines for "ask this on stackoverflow, that on CS"?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Can anyone suggest guidelines for "ask this on stackoverflow, that on CS" ? E.g.
"ask questions about real programs -- why doesn't, how big, how fast --
on stackoverflow,
questions on theory on CStheory, stats, scicomp ..."
But CS.stackexchange looks mostly theoretical too,
its market not clear to me (a separate discussion).
And of course "theory" and "reality" overlap.

If we do want e.g. "algorithm" questions on CS, not stackoverflow,
then we should say that clearly in hovers, and make migrating a bit easier.